Fibration exact sequence in homotopy vs spectral sequence in (co)homology
Perhaps this should be obvious but why is it that one may associate to a fibration exact sequences of topological spaces a long exact sequence of fundamental groups, but in (co)homology, one only has a spectral sequence instead?
I'd love to read any form of explanation.

What kind of answer are you looking for? Both 'sequences' are constructed in standard references on algebraic topology. You can easily follow their proofs if you have enough background.

Thanks for your reply. I mean to ask if there is a certain particular reason that instead of having a fibration exact sequence in cohomology, there is a spectral sequence. What is the source for this asymmetry?

As I said, any relatively advanced monograph on algebraic topology is a possible source. I wonder, though, whether you want a mathematical source or a speculative one. I don't have a taste for the latter but many people seem to like them. The homotopy LES is very easy to construct and you've probably met it before. The total space of a fibration is a twisted cartesian product of the base and the fiber, its singular complex is a twisted tensor product, and such things have a SS, like bicomplexes.

Homotopy groups are obtained by mapping out of a fixed space, cohomology groups are obtained by mapping into a fixed space. Fibration sequences behave well when mapped into (and cofibration sequences behave well when mapped out of).
